# Python boto3 append os.env value

Tags: python, python-2.7, aws-lambda

We have a lambda function that passes values to create an ec2 instance and everytime we test the lambda function we have to manually append the value of the ec2 instance. Is there a way to append os.env value to increment the value vs manual addition or even if we can add time stamp to the parameters within the python function would help.

Comment: your question is a bit unclear. Please try breaking up some of the run on sentences, and be more precise with what you mean by `os.env value` and `parameters`, for example.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Can you edit your question to include your code?